# What is the number of Sylow p subgroups in $S_p$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

I am reading the Wikipedia article entitiled Sylow theorems. This short segment of the article reads:

Part of Wilson's theorem states that
$(p-1)!$ is congruent to  $-1$ (mod $p$) for every prime $p$. One may easily prove this theorem by Sylow's third theorem. Indeed, observe that the number $n_p$ of Sylow's $p$-subgroups in the symmetric group $S_p$ is $(p-2)!$. On the other hand, $n_p ≡ 1$ mod p. Hence, $(p-2)! ≡ 1$ mod $p$. So, $(p-1)! ≡ -1$ mod $p$.

I do not understand why the number of Sylow p-subgroups of $S_p$ is $(p-2)! $

I am taking a course in Group Theory and I have studied everything in Dummit and Foote up to Sylow's theorem. I have also had an introductory course in number theory and am familiar with basic combinatorics.

Comment: see page number 2: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~mnastase/recitation_notes/Ma5a_2012/12Ma5aFinalReview.pdf

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The elements of order $p$ consist of a $p$-cycle of the form $(1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_p)$, where $a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_p$ is a permutation of $2,3,\ldots,p$. So there are exactly $(p-1)!$ elements of order $p$.

Now each subgroup of order $p$ contains $p-1$ elements of order $p$ (i.e. its non-identity elements), and the intersection of any two such subgroups is trivial, so the total number of subgroups of order $p$ is $(p-1)!/(p-1) = (p-2)!$.

Comment: This is one line more than the solution of "see page number $2$" (which is good, of course).

Comment: And it saves one click!

Comment: OK, Thanks. I see now that generally the number of cyclic subgroups of order m in S_n is binomial(n,m)*(m-1)!/phi(m) where phi(m) is the number of positive integers less than m that are relatively prime to m.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as simple as that. For example, when $n=m=6$, in addition to elements like $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$, you also have those like $(1,2)(3,4,5)$.

Comment: Yes,  Thank you Derek Holt.  I agree.  What I think we can say is this:  The number of subgroups in S_n of order p (where p is a prime dividing n) is binomial(n,p)*(p-2)!.

Comment: @Geoffrey Critzer I'm not sure that can be said either. Suppose $p=2$. Then the number of subgroups of order $2$ is the same as the number of involutions on $[n]$ which is equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\binom{n}{2i}(2i-1)!!$ which is nowhere close to $\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: Why the intersection of two  subgroup must be trivial?

Comment: @eraldcoil Each subgroup is cyclic. Suppose $P_1\cap P_2\ni a\neq e$. Then $\langle a\rangle =P_1, P_2$. So the subgroups would be equal.