# Sylow $p$-subgroups in $S_p$ and order $p$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I realise this question has been asked a few times before, but I don't understand the answers.

[What is the number of Sylow p subgroups in S_p?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529038/what-is-the-number-of-sylow-p-subgroups-in-s-p)

- Why are the order $p$ elements in $S_p$ exactly cycles of the form $(1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_p)$? Sure that has order $p$, but why are all order $p$ elements on that form?
- Order $p$ subgroups of $S_p$ contain $p-1$ elements of order $p$, sure. Then Derek Holt says that the intersection of any two such subgroups is trivial. Why is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question: Let $\sigma \in S_p$. Then $\sigma$ can uniquely be written as a product of disjoint cycles. The concatenation of the lengths of these cycles is called the cycle-type of $\sigma$, for example, the cycle type of $(12)(34)$ in $S_5$ is $2$-$2$-$1$. Let $m_1$-..-$m_k$ be the cycle type of $\sigma$. Then $\text{order}(\sigma)=\text{lcm} (m_1,..,m_k)$. This can be seen by noticing disjoint cycles commute, so $\sigma^k=\text{id}$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $m_j$ for all $j$. Now suppose $\text{order}(\sigma)=p$, then $p=\text{lcm}(m_1,..,m_k)$ where $m_1$-..-$m_k$ is the cycle type of $\sigma$. Since $p$ is prime, $p$ is only a multiple of $1$ and $p$, so all $m_j$ are either $1$ or $p$. Obviously they cannot be all $1$ so one must be $p$, but then $k=1$ since $\sum_{i=1}^k m_i = p$. So the cycle type of $\sigma$ is $p$ and the result follows.

For your second question: suppose $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $S_p$ of order $p$, $H \neq K$. Then $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$, so its order is a divisor of $p$. If its order is $p$ then $H \cap K = H = K$, so its order must be $1$. But this implies $H \cap K$ is the trivial group.

Comment: Great answer thank you! This makes everything clear

Comment: I do not understand how $k=1$, could you explain? Why $\sum_{i=1}^km_i=p?$ Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why $k$ must be 1? as one of $m_k$ can be $1$ as one of the cycle can be identity.

Comment: any $\sigma \in S_p$ can be written as $\sigma=\tau_1 .. \tau_k$ where the $\tau_j$ are disjoint cycles of length $m_j$ and $\sum m_j = p$ (any number between $1$ and $p$ will appear exactly once in this expression). If all $\m_j$ are $1$ then $\sigma$ is the identity. If not, then at least one $\m_j$ is $p$. But since this is a sum of natural numbers $\geq 1$ summing to $p$, one of them being equal to $p$ implies there can’t be any others, so $k=1$. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

First point:  a cycle in $S_p$ is usually denoted with the smallest element encountered in the cycle as first element. As it is a cycle of length $p$, the smallest element is $1$.

For the second point, in any group, two subgroups of prime orders intersect trivially because of *Lagrange's theorem*:  the order of the intersection divides the g.c.d. of the orders, so it is $1$ if the orders are different, and if the orders are the same, but the subgroups different.

Comment: The point is why $p$ must be a cycle of length $p$. Why? I do not understand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @briantylf: There seems to be some misunderstanding – $p$ is not a cycle, it is the length of a cycle in $S_p$.

Comment: Sorry. The question should be why a element $\sigma$ in $S_p$ with $|\sigma|=p$ must be a $p$ cycle?

Comment: That's because any permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, and its order is the l.c.m. of the orders of the components. If the l.c.m. is prime, you don't have many choices as to the decomposition.

Comment: Yes. If $\sigma=\sigma_1...\sigma_n$, where $\sigma_1,...\sigma_n$ are disjoint cycles. Then $|\sigma|=lcm(|\sigma_1|,...,|\sigma_n|)$. Then $|\sigma_i|$ can be either $1$ or $p$. Since they are disjoint, I can take $|\sigma_1|=1$, then $\sigma_1=id$. However, as $\sigma_2,...,\sigma_n$ are disjoint $p$ cycles, how to make sure their composition $\sigma$ is still a cycle?

Comment: There can't be two disjoint $p$-cycles since we're in S_p$.

Comment: oh yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have recommended reference for symmetric groups? I have found many books in abstract algebra, but none of them provide good reference for symmetric group and cycles

Comment: Not really. As may people from my generation, I learnt with *Bourbaki*, but it's not really recommended for beginners. I know another general book at the introductory level, which is well written, but it's in french.

Answer (score 0):

On your second bullet: If the intersection is not trivial then it contains an element that has order $p$. This element generates both subgroups so they will coincide. Derek was dealing however with distinct subgroups.